# Reading/Writing to local json file with jQuery (No server involved)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local

I am trying to create a home page for personal use only. I am using local files (HTML, Javascript) and I would like to save data from a todo list I've created to a local JSON file so that the data I write in will be saved between sessions. I've explored a few methods with AJAX, but CORS blocks any request I try to make the straight-forward way.

**How can I take the data I put into my todo list, write it to a JSON file, leave the page, and have it load from that JSON file when I return without involving a server?**

Data is written to the variables already.
Rough idea in code:

```
        // Write to local storage.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../common/todo.json",
            data: {
                item: newItem,
                type: type,
                priority: priority,
                date: dueDate
            }
        });
```

Ideally this would write the data directly to a JSON file I could read from, but CORS blocks these requests and all of the solutions I've found revolve around Node.js or something of the sort, which I cannot use as I want this to stay on my local machine only, and setting up a private server would be well outside the scope of this project.

Comment: For security reasons, web browsers can't write to and read from the local filesystem.

Comment: Short answer is ... You can't. As for using node server that can certainly be used on local machine. Another alternative is using localStorage or indexeddb both built into browser to store data

Comment: You cannot save to a file but you can surely store it in sessionStorage or localStorage of the browser.

Comment: I am just stupid. In the past I had used localStorage and thought that this would only work if I was using a server. I was wrong. Thankfully I had the code already written but had removed it when I ported this code over after closing that server. TLDR: localStorage was the easiest and correct way to implement this in the way I wanted. Thank you all!!!